# Lagged lists in data.table R

Tags: r, list, data.table, lag

`shift` in `R`'s `data.table` is great for time series and time window stuff. But columns of lists don't lag the same way that columns of other elements do.  In the code below, `gearLag` lead/lags `gear` correctly, but `gearsListLag` isn't lagging `gearsList`, instead, `shift` is operating within `gearsList` to lag the element on itself in the same row.

```
dt <- data.table(mtcars)[,.(gear, carb, cyl)]
###  Make col of lists
dt[,carbList:=list(list(unique(carb))), by=.(cyl, gear)]
###  Now I want to lag/lead col of lists
dt[,.(carb, carbLag=shift(carb)
    , carbList, carbListLag=shift(carbList, type="lead")), by=cyl] 

    cyl carb carbLag carbList carbListLag
 1:   6    4      NA         4           NA
 2:   6    4       4         4           NA
 3:   6    1       4         1           NA <-- should be 4 here, not NA
 4:   6    1       1         1           NA
 5:   6    4       1         4           NA
 6:   6    4       4         4           NA
 7:   6    6       4         6           NA
 8:   4    1      NA       1,2         2,NA
 9:   4    2       1       1,2         2,NA
10:   4    2       2       1,2         2,NA
11:   4    1       2       1,2         2,NA
12:   4    2       1       1,2         2,NA
13:   4    1       2       1,2         2,NA
14:   4    1       1         1           NA <-- should be (1,2) here, not NA
15:   4    1       1       1,2         2,NA
16:   4    2       1         2           NA
17:   4    2       2         2           NA
18:   4    2       2       1,2         2,NA
19:   8    2      NA     2,4,3      4, 3,NA
20:   8    4       2     2,4,3      4, 3,NA
21:   8    3       4     2,4,3      4, 3,NA
22:   8    3       3     2,4,3      4, 3,NA
23:   8    3       3     2,4,3      4, 3,NA
```

Any suggestions to lag on lists the same way I lag on other elements?

Comment: It looks like lists are not supported by `shift`. Try `shift(list(list(1,2), list(3,4))) # Error Unsupported type 'list'`. You can tell from the results you're seeing that it is iterating over the list and applying `shift` separately to each element, consistent with what happens when you `shift(.SD)` (with each column, which is a list element, being shifted separately).

Comment: you may want to file an issue on the [github page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues) for an easier way to deal with this

Comment: Closing this as dup since a [better solution was recently implemented](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1595).

Comment: @enfastication, I notice that you were the one who initially filed an issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

This is documented behavior. Here's part of the example at `?shift`:

> ```
> # on lists
> ll = list(1:3, letters[4:1], runif(2))
> shift(ll, 1, type="lead")
> ```

```
# [[1]]
# [1]  2  3 NA
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "c" "b" "a" NA 
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 0.1190792        NA
```

To get around this, you can make a unique ID for each value of the list:

```
dt[, carbList_id := match(carbList, unique(carbList))]

carbList_map = dt[, .(carbList = list(carbList[[1]])), by=carbList_id]

#    carbList_id carbList
# 1:           1        4
# 2:           2      1,2
# 3:           3        1
# 4:           4    2,4,3
# 5:           5        2
# 6:           6      4,8
# 7:           7        6

# or stick with long-form:
carbList_map = dt[, .(carb = carbList[[1]]), by=carbList_id]

#     carbList_id carb
#  1:           1    4
#  2:           2    1
#  3:           2    2
#  4:           3    1
#  5:           4    2
#  6:           4    4
#  7:           4    3
#  8:           5    2
#  9:           6    4
# 10:           6    8
# 11:           7    6
```

Then, just `shift` or whatever with the new ID column. When you need the value of the `carbList` again, you'll have to merge with the new table.

Alternately, if you don't really need to work with the values, but just to browse them, consider making it a string instead, like `carbList:=toString(sort(unique(carb)))` or with `paste0`.

Side note: sort before using `toString`, `paste0` or `list`.

Answer (score 2):

User Frank notes that `shift` doesn't support lists. Here is a solution with `for` and `set` that uses `data.table` to calculate the correct indices for within-group lagging but does all the other work in `for`.  Excepting minor optimizations, is this the best (clean+fast) that I can hope for within `data.table`?

```
dt <- data.table(mtcars)[,.(gear, carb, cyl)]
dt[,carbsList:=list(list(unique(carb))), by=.(cyl, gear)]
dt[,':='(rowLag=shift(.I), gearLag=shift(gear)), by=cyl]
dt[,':='(carbsListLag=list())]
cl_j <- which(names(dt) == "carbsListLag")
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
   set(dt, i, cl_j, dt[dt[i,rowLag], list(carbsList)])
}
dt[,.(carb, gear, gearLag, carbsList, carbsListLag, .I, rowLag), by=cyl]
    cyl carb gear gearLag carbsList carbsListLag  I rowLag
 1:   6    4    4      NA         4         NULL  1     NA
 2:   6    4    4       4         4            4  2      1
 3:   6    1    3       4         1            4  4      2
 4:   6    1    3       3         1            1  6      4
...
13:   4    1    4       4       1,2          1,2 20     19
14:   4    1    3       4         1          1,2 21     20
15:   4    1    4       3       1,2            1 26     21
16:   4    2    5       4         2          1,2 27     26
17:   4    2    5       5         2            2 28     27
18:   4    2    4       5       1,2            2 32     28
19:   8    2    3      NA     2,4,3         NULL  5     NA
20:   8    4    3       3     2,4,3        2,4,3  7      5
```

Comment: The third arg to `set` can be a column name, like "carbsListLag" instead of a number, your `c1_j`. Also , i guess your `:=` can be in one step instead of two..? Finally, might want `NA` in place of `NULL` (I'm not sure).