# Shift a column of lists in data.table by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a column of lists in R:

```
DT <- data.table(foo = c(list(c("a","b","c")), list(c("b","c")), list(c("a","b")), list(c("a"))), id = c(1,1,2,2))
DT
     foo id
1: a,b,c  1
2:   b,c  1
3:   a,b  2
4:     a  2
```

What I would like to do is replicate typical shift behavior to get:

```
     foo id
1:   b,c  1
2:    NA  1
3:     a  2
4:    NA  2
```

For a normal column I would use shift, but this splits the lists into columns and shifts those (and flags a warning):

```
DT[ , shift(foo,1,type = "lead"), by = id]
   id V1 V2
1:  1  b  c
2:  1  c NA
3:  1 NA  c
4:  2  b NA
5:  2 NA NA
```

If I wrap the shift call into a list, the return is a list but only the vector elements have been shifted:

```
DT[ , list(shift(foo,1,type = "lead")), by = id]
   id     V1
1:  1 b,c,NA
2:  1   c,NA
3:  2   b,NA
4:  2     NA
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has come up [more than once](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1595). So I've gone ahead and added this feature. You'll have to use the development version at the moment though, v1.9.7.. see installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

```
DT[, foo2 := shift(.(foo), type = "lead"), 
       by = id]
#      foo id foo2
# 1: a,b,c  1  b,c
# 2:   b,c  1   NA
# 3:   a,b  2    a
# 4:     a  2   NA
```

Just wrap `foo` for each group in a *list*. Note that it returns a *list-of-list* which works well with `:=` as shown above.. If you're not adding/updating your data.table (which doesn't make much sense), then you'll have to extract the list element.

```
DT[, .(foo2 = shift(.(foo), type="lead")[[1L]]), 
        by = id]
#    id foo2
# 1:  1  b,c
# 2:  1   NA
# 3:  2    a
# 4:  2   NA
```

`shift()` is designed to play nicely with data.table's `:=` syntax, since it returns the same number of rows all the time.

Comment: Related, may want to update or dupe close: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38537268/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/36040542/